# P4Eclipse unified Diff

Tags: perforce, unified-diff, p4eclipse

How do I obtain a .patch file in Unified format about the local changes as compared to the depot in Perforce for Eclipse?

I am so used to this feature from CVS that in fact any other Diff format would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to team sync perspective, right click on pending changes then create patch

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice to have this in the standard Eclipse place too, though.